# How can I set up my Ubuntu sever as ipv6 tunnel?

Tags: server, netplan, ipv6, routing, tunnel

I have an Ubuntu server one bare metal that has both ipv6 and ipv4 dedicated, but my home ISP ONLY PROVIDES ME WITH ipv4, is there any sane way of setting up my dedicated server as an IPV6 tunnel provider?

Comment: Please give some detail and what it is your are trying to do. The why might also help. The version of Ubuntu may also help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample netplan configuration for setting up a `sit` ipv6 tunnel.  You will need to provide your own addresses, of course.

```
tunnels:
  ipv6tunnel:
    mode: sit
    remote: xx.yy.zz.aa
    local: XX.YY.ZZ.AA
    addresses: [ "cafe:babe::2/64" ]
    routes:
      - to: default
        via: "cafe:babe::1"
```

This would be the configuration for your home machine.  Your dedicated machine would have the same config, with remote and local addresses reversed, and without a default route.

This requires that you have additional IPv6 addresses routed to your dedicated server, which you are able to route onwards with a tunnel.